# RCTTextField is not a descendant of RCTShadowView error

Tags: javascript, ios, react-native

I'm currently with getting RCTTextField to work with toggling keyboard. Whenever I click on the TextField and keyboard is supposed to toggle I get the following :

```
ExceptionsManager.js:76 view <RCTShadowView: 0x7faa0dcc7e90; viewName: RCTTextField; 
reactTag: 125; frame: {{10, 7.5}, {304, 30}}> (tag #125) is not a descendant of <RCTShadowView: 0x7faa101d0af0; 
viewName: RCTView; reactTag: 18; frame: {{0, 0}, {315, 502}}> (tag #18)
```

I have no idea how to track what the underlying issue might be - looking for some more details or direction in here.

Thanks!

Comment: I am currently running into the exact same issue. I have searched throughout the react-native code starting from where this log is thrown and looking at each of those components, RCTShadowView and RCTTextField, and can't find a clue as to what is going on. The first view, a login view, functions just fine but all other views with inputs run into this problem. I can't seem to isolate the issue on in it's own project either. The only suspicion I can run with is that I started the project in a slightly earlier version of react-native and am updating the project to 0.27.2. Any luck?

Comment: Hey Donald - the issue in my case was react-native-keyboard-aware-scroll-view component. Here is more info : https://github.com/APSL/react-native-keyboard-aware-scroll-view/issues/33

Also a related facebook issue : https://github.com/facebook/react-native/pull/7876

Comment: That really explains everything, you have provided the missing link to the pesky problem that has been keeping me from sleeping. Now it makes sense why it works on one page and not the others. Thank you!

Comment: Glad I could help :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have found out what the problem in my case was - as the answer seems to help people solve similar issues here it is :

In my projects the offending piece was react-native-keyboard-aware-scroll-view. [It was a known issue](https://github.com/APSL/react-native-keyboard-aware-scroll-view/issues/33) but pretty hard to track down. Another link that might be helpful - [#7876](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/pull/7876)